# SQL filtering - what's missing from the SQL code

Tags: sql, filtering

trying to filter some totals in SQL but something is missing. End results are Each region (4 rows) with only totals for several (3 columns) types of papers.  tried count and sum but still missing something

```
SELECT r.name AS region, o.standard_amt_usd, o.poster_amt_usd, o.gloss_amt_usd 
FROM orders o
JOIN accounts a ON o.account_id = a.id
JOIN sales_reps s ON a.sales_rep_id = s.id
JOIN region r ON s.region_id = r.id
WHERE o.standard_amt_usd = total_amt_usd OR o.poster_amt_usd = total_amt_usd OR 
o.gloss_amt_usd = total_amt_usd 
AND NOT NULL
ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

Comment: `AND NOT NULL` <-- what does this do?

Comment: The syntax to check for nulls is typically: `<expr> IS [NOT] NULL`.

Comment: what is the console output?